# How to use sed command to replace the string in linux?

Tags: linux

I have String like below .

```
hd_ma_prod_customer_ro:*:123456789:john.doe
```

Basically I need to look for the last colon (:) and Replace everything after last colon(:) .

Output for the above string : `hd_ma_prod_customer_ro:*:123456789:replacedString`

By using sed how can I do this.Any one help me.

Comment: Best is by starting to try yourself, then reading the man page for the command you want to learn: `man sed`. Also looking at examples is a very good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following `sed` command will do what you want:

```
s/:[^:]*$/:replacedString/
```

What it's replacing is a colon followed by any number of non-colons, at the end of the string.

What it replaces it with is the colon plus your text.

See the following transcript for details:

```
pax$ echo 'hd_ma_prod_customer_ro:*:123456789:john.doe' | sed 's/:[^:]*$/:replacedString/'
hd_ma_prod_customer_ro:*:123456789:replacedString
```